# common lisp maplist with append output

Tags: common-lisp

In the Hyperspec they have this example for maplist:

```
(maplist #'append '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2) '(1 2 3))
=> ((1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3) (2 3 4 2 2 3))
```

which I don't quite grasp. Following the apparent logic, I would have guessed

```
=>((1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3) (2 3 4 2 2 3) (3 4 3) (4))
```

It seems that because we've "exhausted" the middle list after producing the two sublists, it's game over. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: As a point of etiquette: you don't seem to have selected answers to any of your questions -- you should consider doing this for the answer that (best) answers each of your questions. This does two things: (1) it gives credit to the person whose answer helped you and (2) lets others who view the question&answers know the solution to your problem. (To select an answer, click on the check-mark by the answer, making it appear green.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion that it stops after the middle list is "exhausted" seems to be correct; from [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#maplist):

> maplist is like mapcar except that function is applied to successive sublists of the lists. *function* is first applied to the lists themselves, and then to the cdr of each list, and then to the cdr of the cdr of each list, and so on.

So it makes sense that it would stop after hitting the end of the shortest list, because there would be no more values to use from that list and it seems to try to use all the (sub)lists each time 'round.

**EDIT**

As [Samuel Edwin Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894885/samuel-edwin-ward) pointed out:

> The part describing mapcar includes "The iteration terminates when the shortest list runs out, and excess elements in other lists are ignored."

---

Just a quick REPL experiment:

```
[1]> (maplist #'append '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2) '(1 2 3))
((1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3) (2 3 4 2 2 3))
[2]> (maplist #'append '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3) '(1 2))
((1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2) (2 3 4 2 3 2))
[3]> (maplist #'append '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3) '(1 2 5))
((1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 5) (2 3 4 2 3 2 5) (3 4 3 5))
```

Comment: The part describing `mapcar` includes "The iteration terminates when the shortest list runs out, and excess elements in other lists are ignored."

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Thanks! I've updated my answer. (Guess I should have read more of the docs myself!)

Comment: No problem.  I feel like they really make the reader jump through hoops to avoid repeating themselves on that particular page.  `mapcon` is just like `maplist` except with this difference, and `maplist` is just like `mapcar` except with that difference... could they just tell us what `mapcon` does?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Yeah, that does get annoying. From a documenter's stand-point (as a programmer) I tend to want to do that sort of thing to avoid information duplication -- not wanting to have to update something in multiple places -- but as a programmer trying to figure out what something does it is _very_ annoying.